# Swapping between multi-line plots with different numbers of lines D3

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to essentially merge these two examples

https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/line_change_data.html

https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/line_several_group.html

But for the life of me I cannot get it to work. The data is coming in from pandas/flask so I have complete control on how to format it.

I also tried to simply feed in different datasets into the multiline plot (i.e. not worry about updating in a fancy transition, just swap between plots) but it kept just drawing the new lines without removing the old ones (i googled for various .exit() and .remove() strategies, but either it didn't work or removed the whole picture)

I feel the transition might be complicated as my understanding is one needs to give new data to the old points on the axis, but if that line doesn't exist in the new plot what would happen?

EDIT: Okay so I found a way to just switch between plots and refresh things with the following code, in particular by removing all the 'g' elements and then redrawing the axes which are lost in this (as you can tell I am still learning the ropes as to the different components). I tried only removing line and path elements but that did not work, would appreciate input on that too please.

So in this case, how would I go about updating this using transitions?

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Add 2 buttons -->
<button onclick="update(data1)">Dataset 1</button>
<button onclick="update(data2)">Dataset 2</button>
<button onclick="update(d_all)">Dataset 3</button>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
<script>
    var data1 = {{ d1|safe }}
    var data2 = {{ d2|safe }}
    var d_all = {{ d_all | safe}}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts/test.js') }}"></script>
```

JS

```
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Initialise a X axis:
var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0,width]);
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x);

// Initialize an Y axis
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y);


// Create a function that takes a dataset as input and update the plot:
function update(data) {
  d3.selectAll("g > *").remove()
  svg.append("g")
  .attr("class","myYaxis")
  svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .attr("class","myXaxis")

  // Create the X axis:
  x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.ser1 }) ]);
  svg.selectAll(".myXaxis") //.transition()
    // .duration(3000)
    .call(xAxis);

  // create the Y axis
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.ser2  }) ]);
  svg.selectAll(".myYaxis")
    // .transition()
    // .duration(3000)
    .call(yAxis);

  var grouped = d3.nest() // nest function allows to group the calculation per level of a factor
    .key(function(d) { return d.l;})
    .entries(data);

   // color palette
  var res = grouped.map(function(d){ return d.key }) // list of group names

  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(res)
    .range(['#e41a1c','#377eb8','#4daf4a','#984ea3','#ff7f00','#ffff33','#a65628','#f781bf','#999999'])

  // Draw the line
  svg.selectAll(".line")
      .data(grouped)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", function(d){ return color(d.key) })
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
        .attr("d", function(d){
          return d3.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.ser1); })
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.ser2); })
            (d.values)
        })

}

update(d_all)
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay I more or less have a working answer for this, it's not perfect but it deals with the bulk of it as far as i can tell.

Watching this video helped a lot too so kudos there
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IyIAR65G-GQ

```
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Initialise a X axis:
var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0,width]);
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x);

// Initialize an Y axis
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class","myYaxis")
  svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .attr("class","myXaxis")


// Create a function that takes a dataset as input and update the plot:
function update(data) {

  // Create the X axis:
  x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.ser1 }) ]);
  svg.selectAll(".myXaxis") //.transition()
    // .duration(3000)
    .call(xAxis);

  // create the Y axis
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.ser2  }) ]);
  svg.selectAll(".myYaxis")
    // .transition()
    // .duration(3000)
    .call(yAxis);


  var grouped = d3.nest() // nest function allows to group the calculation per level of a factor
    .key(function(d) { return d.l;})
    .entries(data);


  var res = grouped.map(function(d){ return d.key }) // list of group names
  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(res)
    .range(['#e41a1c','#377eb8','#4daf4a','#984ea3','#ff7f00','#ffff33','#a65628','#f781bf','#999999'])

 var update = svg.selectAll(".line")
             .data(grouped);

  var t01Enter =  update.enter().append("g")
                           .attr("class", ".line");
  t01Enter.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .style("opacity", 0.0)
        .merge(update)
         .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .style("opacity", 1.0)
        .attr("d", function(d){
          return d3.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.ser1); }) 
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.ser2); })
            (d.values)
        })
        .style("stroke",  function(d){ return color(d.key) })
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      update.exit()
      .transition().duration(1000).style("opacity", 0.0).remove()
}

update(d_all)
```

I'd still like to work out how to chain the transitions more carefully and avoid issues of returning a type transition to merge, but that's for the next post!